# Doing a group by on rows which are together in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a legacy data which looks like this

[image]

The result that I want is this

[image]

What I want is a group by and then select the top row from the group.If the same group appears again in the database I want the top row from that as well.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And how do you define "top row"? Rows in a table are not sorted. You need some criteria to sort by if you want to find the "top row".

Comment: The DBMS is SQL server and by top I mean the order of insertion in the database.

Comment: Again: rows in a table are **not** sorted. So there is no such thing as "order of insertion".

Comment: What I mean is when you select rows from a table without doing any order by, and then select the first row out of rows with same value for 2 columns

Comment: You cannot rely on the order of rows *without* an order by. The database is free to choose any order it seems fit. If you want to identify something like "the first row" you **have** to have some column that can be used to define a sort order.

Answer (score 0):

```
select experimentID, Experiment, Status from yourtable 
group by experimentID, Experiment, Status
order by status, experimentID
```

Comment: That is invalid (standard) SQL and will not work in any DBMS except for MySQL with it's "loose" (aka "broken") group by implementation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, corrected to fit any DB. but after some comments it is not clear if this helps OP